# PL/SQL How to call a stored function within a stored procedure

Tags: plsql

How can I call a function within a stored procedure?

This is what I have so far:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE DELETE_ALL_CUSTOMERS_VIASQLDEV( pcustid number, pcustname Varchar2)
 AS


BEGIN

   DELETE_ALL_CUSTOMERS_FROM_DB(pcustid, pcustname);


    dbms_output.put_line('--------------------------------------------');
    dbms_output.put_line('Deleting all Customer rows');
    dbms_output.put_line('999 rows deleted');
    commit;
    raise_application_error(-20000, 'An error was encountered' || SQLERRM);


END;
```

Error I get:

```
Procedure DELETE_ALL_CUSTOMERS_VIASQLDEV compiled

LINE/COL  ERROR
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------
7/4       PL/SQL: Statement ignored
7/4       PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'DELETE_ALL_CUSTOMERS_FROM_DB'
Errors: check compiler log
```

Comment: Add to your post the procedure Delete_All_Customers_from_db. The actual parameters in the calling statement appears to be different from the formal parameters in the definition. There are either additional formal parameters or the type of then do not correspond to the parameter types "pcustid" and "pcustname" defined for the Delete_All_Customers_Viasqldev routine.

Answer (score 0):

You should have `DELETE_ALL_CUSTOMERS_FROM_DB` with same parameters as:

```
 create or replace PROCEDURE DELETE_ALL_CUSTOMERS_FROM_DB( pcustid number, pcustname Varchar2)
  AS
 BEGIN
     dbms_output.put_line('Inside');
  END;
```